# Est-ce qu'écrire « ça » au lieu de « cela » est si grave que ça ?

Tags: usage, choix-de-mot, contractions

Je sais que *ça ne se fait pas* d'écrire « ça », mais j'ai peine à situer la gravité de son utilisation. « Cela » me semble souvent être trop formel, voir sonner faux.

Comment: PS: couldn't think off-hand of an appropriate translation for awkward.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Write it in English and I'll translate it if you want.

Comment: He wants to know if using "ça" before a verb isn't too 'familiar' (not sure if it's the  word in english).

Comment: @Benjol maladroit

Comment: Si tu viens de le dire tu devras utiliser *ceci* au lieu de *cela*.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Le pronom *cela* est préférable dans un texte formel. Le pronom *ça* est largement accepté oralement et dans un texte informel.

Comment: Le "pronom" serait plus précis que le "mot".

Comment: @wok: Exact ! J'ai corrigé la réponse.

Comment: @Laurent, merci. Donc Twitter, Blog, Email, Lettre privée OK; CV, lettre de motivation, roman NON?

Comment: @Benjol: En effet. Cepdendant, un roman pourra utiliser le pronom *ça* pour refléter l'expression orale du narrateur ou des personnages.

Answer (score 4):

*Le Bon usage* brosse un portrait intéressant de la situation :

> La **concurrence de *cela* et *ça*.** Les deux formes sont, du point de vue syntaxique, presque toujours interchangeables, mais la première prédomine dans la langue écrite et la seconde dans la langue parlée. Il serait exagéré pourtant de considérer que, dans l'écrit, *ça* n'apparaît que là où l'auteur fait parler un personnage.
>
> - *Pellisson avait trop de goût pour parler de* ÇA (François-René de Chateaubriant, *Vie de Rancé). — Les criminels dégoûtent comme des châtrés : moi, je suis intact, et* ÇA *m'est égal* (Arthur Rimbaud, *Une saison en enfer).*
>
> [...]
> Dans les expressions qui sont surtout de la langue parlée, *cela* est rare et peu naturel. Il détonnereait dans ce passage : *Quand les autres y sont déjà enfermés depuis plus de trois heures, avec les godasses, la transpiration, les pieds et les fenêtres closes, et que* ÇA *chelingue, je vous prie de croire* (Louis Aragon, *Beaux quartiers).*

Une note historique spécifie de plus que :

> *Ça* est une forme contractée de *cela* : comparez les prononciations /py/ pour *plus* et /sɥi/ pour *celui*. [...] — Le mot est bien attesté au XVIIe siècle : Molière le met dans la bouche de ses paysans *(Don Juan,* II, 3 ; etc.) ; La Fontaine l'emploie dans une lettre de 1661 : *[orthographe modernisée par l'éditeur] On a de l'inquiétude pour M. Pellison : si* ÇA *est, c'est encore un grand surcroît de malheur.* [...] — Il faut attendre le XIXe siècle pour que le mot pénètre vraiment dans l'écrit (quoique, nous l'avons dit, il n'y ait pas ses libres entrées).

Il semble donc que les différences soient subtiles, et que les règles ne soient le plus souvent qu'une conception personnelle de ce qui est acceptable ou non<sup>1</sup>. On peut selon son désir décider de suivre l'usage habituel à la lettre, ou de commettre à son encontre quelques incartades occasionnelles et calculées, sans que ça ne donne prise à des objections vraiment valides.

Aller systématiquement à l'encontre de l'usage commun (surtout à l'oral) serait par contre selon moi moins judicieux, mais chacun est libre de s'amuser comme bon lui plaît.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Mais pas toujours ! Pour ajouter à l’exemple d’Aragon cité par *Le Bon usage*, Stéphane Gimenez a donné en commentaire ci-dessous, par boutade, un excellent exemple d'utilisation abusive de *cela* : « Eh ben! *CELA* c’est vrai! », à quoi j’ai répondu par une autre phrase du même accabit : « *CELA* alors! ». Pour un exemple du contraire (un *ça* étrange et inattendu), on peut penser à une opposition avec *ceci* : « Découlant de ceci et de *ÇA*, le nombre π est irrationnel »</sub>

Comment: Eh ben, cela c'est vrai !

Comment: Cela alors! Serait-ce plus compliqué qu'il ne semble?