# When to use “J'ai mangé ça” or “Je l'ai mangé”?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

Given a sentence constructed as such:

```
Subject - auxiliary verb - past participle - object  
I        have              eaten             it
J'       ai                mangé             ça
```

or

```
Subject - object - auxiliary verb - past participle
I         it       have             eaten
Je        l'       ai               mangé
```

Are both options grammatical? Which is used more widely? Does it change for different verbs?

---

Étant donné une phrase comme ça:

```
Sujet - verbe auxiliaire - participe passé - objet  
J'      ai                mangé             ça
I       have              eaten             it
```

ou

```
Sujet - objet - verbe auxiliaire - participe passé
Je       l'     ai                mangé
I        it     have              eaten
```

Est-ce que les deux formulations sont correctes ? Laquelle est la plus utilisée ? Est-ce que ça dépend du verbe ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> J'ai mangé cela

gives

> I have eaten that

but

> Je l'ai mangé

gives

> I have eaten it.

Comment: Is the `ça` in the question just wrong and I should favour `ce` and `cela`?

Comment: @JamesWebster: `ça` is an abbreviation of `cela`

Comment: French lessons for 4 years, admittedly with a LOT forgotten, and a few years of hobbyist French and I never knew that!

Comment: @JamesWebster Regarding *ça* vs *cela*, see [When to use celui vs cela vs ça?](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/3039/when-to-use-celui-vs-cela-vs-ca) and [Est-ce qu'écrire « ça » au lieu de « cela » est si grave que ça ?](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23/est-ce-quecrire-ca-au-lieu-de-cela-est-si-grave-que-ca)

Comment: Une explication du vote négatif serait bienvenue!

Answer (score 2):

Use “*je l'ai mangé*” when you speak of a definite thing known by the person you talk to.
Use “*j'ai mangé ça*” when you speak of something you can only point to, or something that is hard (or that you don't want) to define. *Ça*  can also have depreciative connotations in some contexts (which *cela* or *ceci* may also have).

This distinction only involve pronouns and is independent of the verb. For instance one use “je l'ai écrite” for a letter but “j'ai écrit ça” for the content (the first time you refer to it).